# Using wildcard characters and escaping apostophes in Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, wildcard, apostrophe

I am trying to do a query which pulls a date based on a name from a cell that contains many names separated by commas that was created by a Google form.

This using the wildcards will pull all the dates from any name that is in B except give an error when the name contains an apostrophe:

```
=QUERY("SOURCE", "select max(D) where (B like '%"&$A$7&"%') Label max(D) ''", 0)
```

Alternatively, often times B only has a single name so I can run the following query and pull the date I need if B only has a single name even with an apostrophe.

```
=QUERY("SOURCE", "select max(D) where (B like """&$A$7&""") Label max(D) ''", 0)
```

What I can't figure out is how to use the wildcard characters and escape the apostrophe at the same time.

Comment: Please add data sample and desired result sample.

Comment: [Here is a working link to an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7_E15ktJKo1Q02xx3yG67mVBqecNitxiVGz8MZybiM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe filter() is easier to use in this situation? Assuming names are separated with a comma (and a space), try

```
=if(len(G4)*len(F6), max(filter(B3:B, regexmatch(A3:A, G6), regexmatch(C3:C, F6))),)
```

Change ranges to suit.
If that doesn't help, please share an example spreadsheet.

Comment: [I added an example spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7_E15ktJKo1Q02xx3yG67mVBqecNitxiVGz8MZybiM/edit?usp=sharing). The query is a little more complicated than I put above because there is another like statement where it tries to find a category of training. I am new to this and unfamiliar with all of those functions so I will do some reading.

Comment: I got it to work in column L. I had to switch the first regexmatch expression to the data validated name cell. Can you explain why you have the If function? Is that to leave a blank if the columns aren't complete? It seems to function fine without it.